# change image border by accessing html tree

Tags: html, css

```
<ul class="xoxo blogroll">
    <li>
        <a href="" target="_blank"><img src="x.png" alt="image"></a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="" target="_blank"><img src="x2.png" alt="image2"></a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="" target="_blank"><img src="x3.png" alt="image3"></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

and now i want to remove the border from .

i try with:

```
ul.xoxo.blogroll li img {
    border: none;
}
```

but not working. Is syntax correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

some selectors are :

```
ul.blogroll li img {
    border: none;
}
```

or :

```
ul.xoxo li img {
    border: none;
}
```

or :

```
li img {
    border: none;
}
```

or :

```
ul li img {
    border: none;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

There is no element on the page with `class="xoxblogroll"`. You can use the following, if you want the two classes to be present:

```
ul.blogroll.xoxo li img {
    border: none;
}
```

Comment: sorry this is what i already try but not working. I just have ul.xoxo.blogroll

Comment: here's a sample that shows that the styles are applied: http://jsbin.com/ovanug/1/edit -- does it differ from your situation?

Answer (score 1):

That space in your `class="xoxo blogroll"` means the browser interprets the ul as having 2 classes, "xoxo" and "blogroll"

Either remove the space from your class definition like this: `class="xoxoblogroll"`, or select only one of the 2 words in your css, like this:

```
ul.xoxo li img {
    border: none;
}
```

or

```
ul.blogroll li img {
    border: none;
}
```

or concatenate the 2 classes in your CSS as follows, if both class names have to be present:

```
ul.xoxo.blogroll li img {
    border: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi now write **this css**

```
.xoxo.blogroll li img{
border:0;
}
```

**or** now you **should remove** `text decoration none`

as like this

```
.xoxo.blogroll li a{
text-decoration:none;
outline:0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. give proper way of the image identification like this

```
ul.xoxo.blogroll li a img {
border: none;
}
```

or

```
ul.xoxo.blogroll li a img {
border: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your class selector is correct, are you sure you can just push the two class names together like that? Try:

```
ul.xoxo li img {
    border: none;
}
```

or

```
ul.blogroll li img {
    border: none;
}
```